# pivot data in mysql based on dates and column values

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I have my data in the below format:

```
  Date.       Comapany col3.    Quantity
'01/01/2018',  'CompA','x','10'
'12/01/2017',  'CompA','x','20'
'11/01/2017',  'CompA','x','30'
'10/01/2017',  'CompA','x','40'
'01/01/2018',  'CompB','x','40'
'12/01/2017',  'CompB','x','20'
'11/01/2017',  'CompB','x','30'
'10/01/2017',  'CompB','x','40'
```

I want to pivot the data to the below format, i tried pivoting but it didn't work.

**Can someone help me here ? All of my col values are coming same**

**Required output:**

```
Company col3    date    PeriodValue Lastmonth   last_to_last
A   x        01/01/2018     10         20        30
A   x        12/01/2017     20         30        40
A   x        11/01/2017     30         40        0
A   x        10/01/2017     40          0        0
B   x        01/01/2018     40         20        30
B   x        12/01/2017     20         30        40
B   x        11/01/2017     30         40        0
B   x        10/01/2017     40          0        0
```

**query**

```
select inr.date,inr.Company,inr.col3 , sum(inr.value)  as Periodvalue  ,
sum(case when period=STR_TO_DATE(inr.period,'%m/%d/%Y') -INTERVAL 1 MONTH  THEN inr.value else 0 end) as Lastmonth,
sum(case when period=STR_TO_DATE(inr.period,'%m/%d/%Y') -INTERVAL 2 MONTH  THEN inr.value else 0 end) as last_to_last from (
select concat(SUBSTRING(Period, 5, 6),"/","01","/",SUBSTRING(Period, 1, 4)) as period,Company,Metric,v1 as value
from test2.q3) inr
group by inr.period,inr.Company,inr.Metric  order by period
```

**myoutput**

```
Company col3    date    PeriodValue Lastmonth   last_to_last
A   x        01/01/2018     10         10        30
A   x        12/01/2017     20         20        20
A   x        11/01/2017     30         30        30
A   x        10/01/2017     40         40        40
B   x        01/01/2018     40         40        40
B   x        12/01/2017     20         20        20
B   x        11/01/2017     30         30        30
B   x        10/01/2017     40         40       40
```

[my problem is something similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509426/mysql-pivot-table-dates-on-column-name)

Comment: What is the data type of date?

Comment: @forpas it is date

Comment: In your sample data there is only 1 row per company/date so why do you sum? Also if Date's data type is DATE why do you use STR_TO_DATE()? Also in your code there are column names like Metric, v1 that do not exist in your sample data.

Comment: Because that is sample data and I have a lot of data @forpas

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of MySql, you could easily achieve what you want using window functions.

Assuming your input data is the one you provided from a table with the format:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(`Date` date,
 Company varchar(32),
 col3 varchar(1),
 Quantity int
);
```

You could run this to get what you want :

```
select RIGHT(Company,1) as Company
,col3
,`Date`
,Quantity as PeriodValue
,LAG(Quantity,1)OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY `Date` ASC) LastMonth
,LAG(Quantity,2)OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY `Date` ASC ) SecondtoLastMonth
from test
ORDER BY Company ASC,`Date` DESC
```

Comment: lag will not work here what I want is suppose if my period value is 01/01/2018  then last month's value 12/01/2017 has value 20 which should get populated as last month